# "again" word: 二度｛にど｝, 再び｛ふたたび｝ - usage, difference

Tags: word-choice, polarity-items

Do they mean the same thing when used as a sequence word ("again, a second time") or is there any difference (apart from 二度 also being used to mean "two times")?

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence where 二度 is better translated as *again*? I think 二度 almost always means *twice*...

Comment: There are plenty. Here : http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/22066/m0u/%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6/

あそこへは決して二度と行かない
I will never go there again.

Then also here: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/57449/m0u/%E4%BA%8C%E5%BA%A6/

Comment: But that is 二度と, not 二度.

Comment: Ok, so that how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only in ***negative*** sentences, 「[二度]{にど}と」, not「二度」, can mean "again".

「マクドナルドへは**二度と**[行]{い}かない！」= "I'll never go to McDonald's again!"

In affirmative sentences, 「二度」 always means "twice".  「二度と」 cannot be used in affirmative sentences.

「日本に**二度**行ったことがあります。」= "I have been to Japan twice."

「[再]{ふたた}び」 means "again" in any situation.

「[去年]{きょねん}**再び**日本に行った。」 means "I went to Japan again last year."  This means that you had been to Japan at least once before last year as well.

「去年**二度**日本に行った。」 is completely different.  It means "I went to Japan twice last year."